# A retraction $r:X\to A$ such that $r$ is not a closed mapping

Tags: general-topology

In a topology exercise, I was able to find an example of a retraction $r:X\to A$ such that $r$ is not an open mapping. For example, take $r:\mathbb{R}\to[0,2]$ defined by $$r(x)=\begin{cases}0\quad\qquad\text{ if }x\leq0\\x\quad\qquad\text{ if }0\leq x\leq2\\4-x\quad\,\text{ if }2\leq x\leq3\\x-2\,\quad\text{ if }3\leq x\leq4\\2\qquad\quad\,\text{ if }x\geq4\end{cases}$$

Now I was wondering if it is possible to do the same, but then for a retraction $r$ that is not a closed mapping. So a continuous mapping $r:X\to A$ such that $r_{|A}=\mathrm{id}_A$, with a closed $C\subset X$ such that $r(C)\subset A$ is not closed. I couldn't think of an example, and also couldn't think of a reason why such a mapping might not exist. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection map $\pi:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is an example.

Comment: I see, thank you! Didn't know it was this simple :)

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Notice every retraction is a quotient map. What is an example of a quotient map but not a closed map? A projection.

Comment: Thank you, I knew the first fact but I didn't come up with the connection myself